Eigenfunctions of Integral Equations
According to Riley, Hobson and Bence's Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering, the notions of eigenvalues and eigenfunctions are applicable to Fredholm integral equations. Consider the following integral equation:
$y(x) = \lambda \int_0^\pi \sin(x + z)y(z)dz$
According to the authors, the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of this equation are
$\lambda_1 = \frac{2}{\pi}, \,\,\, y_1(x) = A(\sin x + \cos x)$
$\lambda_2 = -\frac{2}{\pi}, \,\,\, y_2(x) = B(\sin x - \cos x)$
The authors also said that these two eigenfunctions form a complete set. But in which function space do these two eigenfunctions form a complete set? It seems that the function space cannot be the space of all continuous functions with $[0, \pi]$ as domain. For example, $y(x) = 1$ is a continuous function in the domain $[0, \pi]$. But it is clear that this function cannot be expressed as the sum of these two eigenfunctions.

$y_1$ and $y_2$ span the space of eigenfunctions.  Any linear combination of them is another eigenfunction.

The operator $T y = \int_0^\pi \sin(x + z) y(z) d z$ has rank 2. Here $y_1$ and $y_2$ belong to the space spanned by $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ which is also the image of $T$. The rest of the eigenfunctions are $\Ker T$ which is the set of functions orthogonal to $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. Also not that $T$ is self-adjoint in $L^2(0,\pi)$.
